# Markdown in GitLab editor: combine bullet list with multi-line code

Tags: gitlab, markdown

I am trying to write Markdown (for wiki) in GitLab editor with bullet list, with the possibility that the bullet list contains multi-line code.

I tried with this code:

````
- Test
```javascript
var somecode = 5;
somecode++;
```
- Another line
````

but this gives me strange results:

[image: screenshot - multi-line code starts in the same line as the first bullet point]

If I add an additional empty line between `-` and ```` ``` ````:

````
- Test

```javascript
var somecode = 5;
somecode++;
```
- Another line
````

I get better results, but the code is not aligned with the bullet list:

[image: screenshot of the result - code is not aligned with bullet list]

Here are the expected results:

[image: expected result]

How can I achieve the upper design? (Code has margin on the right to align with the bullet list content.)

Comment: Have you tried your first solution with two spaces after test?

Comment: Just did, and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use **an empty line and four spaces** before the multi-line code:

````
- Test

    ```javascript
var somecode = 5;
somecode++;
```
- Another line
````

**Result:**

[image: result of the formatting]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the behaviour changed with recent Gitlab releases (the Markdown processor changed in version 11.1 on July 22, 2018) since @tamás-sengel answer does not work with (at least) Gitlab 13.0.5.

You should simply align the code block with the first letter of the text using as many spaces as required. No new line is necessary between the text and the code block.

For example, the following markdown :

````
As of this day, the following actions are available :
 - Building libraries (with automated tests) :
   ```bash
   DOCKERFILE_TARGET="build-libs" docker-compose build
     --pull
     --no-cache
     libs
   ```
 - Building the application (with automated tests) :
````

renders as :
[image: Markdown list rendering]